# Accessing objects of a property in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I don't know if the title somehow misleading I am a beginner here, but I want to ask if I have something like this

```
 var someObject ={}           
                someObject.info= {
                    name: "value" 
};
```

how could I access name? I tried

```
someObject.info.name
```

but it seems nonsense

Comment: You sure? http://jsfiddle.net/2kzh4v56/

Comment: Can you please define _"but it seems nonsense"_? That's not really a problem we can replicate and/or solve.

Comment: @BobfCali that's not a problem here

Answer (score 3):

Call it what you want, but yes, that is one way you can access properties of an object.

1. `someObject.info.name`
2. `someObject["info"]["name"]`
3. `someObject.info["name"]`